# Cannot make call from one php file to another php file

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have 3 files: `fileNum1.php`, `fileNum2.php` and `fileNum3.php`.

`fileNum1.php` file makes a call for `fileNum2.php` file:

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","fileNum2.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

and `fileNum2.php` makes a call for `fileNum3.php`:

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","fileNum3.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

The call to `fileNum3.php` is NOT WORKING!
What is the the problem?
(Can it be because I've started `new XMLHttpRequest` inside existing `XMLHttpRequest`?)

Comment: You can't call a file thats calls another with AJAX. In your second file, you should include fileNum3.php (fileNum3 will have a function that will return the desired data) and print (in the second file) what you got from the function.

Comment: Stumped as to why someone would downvote this question. It's a good question.

Comment: @Guy If the PHP returns JavaScript, I think it could be executed.

Comment: @tom He has AJAX in the second PHP file, so the AJAX script will be returns too (it echo's). You can't return only a part of the file, it will get it's content

Comment: Try using jquery, it is much more easier

Comment: @guy I don't think we are understandingly each other. It is possible for fileNum2.php to generate the code given. That's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client-side code. This means that a browser is required to interpret and execute the JavaScript code.

If you access `fileNum1.php` via a browser, the call to `fileNum2.php` will execute, as the JavaScript for `fileNum1.php` is interpreted.

The call from `fileNum2.php` to `fileNum3.php` will NOT execute, as it is not returned to the browser. The JavaScript on the 3rd file will be returned as output to the server, which is making the request, and the JavaScript will never make it back to the browser.

If you want an action from `fileNum3.php` to return to `fileNum1.php`, you will have to catch the data when `fileNum3.php` is called on `fileNum2.php`, and then return the response to `fileNum1.php`.

Or, you can do it the right way and say if `fileNum1.php` called `fileNum2.php` and everything was ok, then call `fileNum3.php`.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    // code for IE6, IE5 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","fileNum2.php",false);
xmlhttp.send(); 

if(xmlhttp.responseText !== "undefined"){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp2.open("GET","fileNum3.php",false);
    xmlhttp2.send(); 
}
```